# Background-color applying for individual images instead of container

Tags: css

I have 2 images in container & i want to apply background-color for whole container as below image :

[image]

But instead of container, background-color is applying for individual images as in below code snippet....

It Looks simple to solve, it may be simple, but I am just css beginner & really tried lot before posting question....

```js
var mask1;

let jsonData = {
  "path" : " newyear collage\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "newyear collage",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "newyear collage",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle"
        },
        {
          "x" : 160,
          "height" : 296,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 296,
              "src" : "vw6ZYre.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 429,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 188,
              "y" : 122,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 291,
          "width" : 429,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,
          "height" : 324,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 324,
              "src" : "kbXMnVP.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 471,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_2"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 209,
              "y" : 136,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse_2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 22,
          "width" : 471,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "newyearcollage08"
    }
  ]
};


$(document).ready(function() 
{

    var maskedImageUrla = "";
    var coordinates = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };

    var width = 0;
    var height = 0;

    function json(data)
 {
        var dataObj = {};
        let layer1 = data.layers;
        let layer2 = layer1[0].layers;
  
  for (i = 1; i < layer2.length; i++)
  {
    var x = layer2[i].x;
    var y = layer2[i].y;
    var src = layer2[i].layers[0].src;
        $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

        var mask1 = $(".container").mask({
            maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src, 
            onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                img.css({
                    "position": "fixed",
                    "left": x + "px", 
                    "top": y + "px"   
                });
            }
        });

        fileupa1.onchange = function() {
            mask1.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileupa1.files[0]));
        };
    }
 
 }
 json(jsonData);

}); // end of document ready

// jq plugin for mask
(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            container.selected(evt);
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
            if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                    return; // position has not changed
                settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                container.updateStyle();
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };

                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 0);
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp
{
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; 
display: flex;
background :gold;
}

.container
{
 border: 1px slolid #DDDDDD; 
display: flex; 
background :silver !important;
width: 612px;
  height: 612px;
}


.container canvas {
 display: block;
 
 background :black;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 50px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
image 1 
<input id="fileupa1" type="file" >

<div class="container">
</div>
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/aMvyYg

Comment: You specifically set inline dimentions for your container here `$(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px")` (width and height are declared at 0). And inline styles take over on CSS rules. It has a background color but you can't see it because the dimensions are 0*0.

Comment: @Kaddath Thanks for suggestion, but i also have `addClass('temp');` css in that line   `$(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');` & in <style> i gave `.temp
{ background :gold;
}` , so i thought it will work......

Comment: @Kaddath you can post this as an answer..... i will add some height and width for container instead of just 0*0......

Comment: so we can conclude if `height & width` are zero , than background-color will not apply.....

Comment: Here is codepen, i added height and width for container dynamically & background-color is working fine : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/KEdZaZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you solved the problem, but also asked for an answer, so I will just post the relevant part:

The point is that if the HTML code has inline style (with a `style` attribute, and this is whar jQuery's `css()` does) it will take precedence over styles applied in a CSS `<style>` tag or file. You can prevent this behaviour by adding `!important` to your CSS rule so it takes precedence (but it is usually not recommended). Remember that inline style will still be the one applied if both have the `!important`:

```css
.test {
  background-color: blue;
}

.test2 {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" style="background-color: red";>this div has background-color inline style</div>
<div class="test">this div has no background-color inline style</div>
<div class="test2" style="background-color: yellow !important;">this div has background-color inline style with !important</div>
<div class="test2" style="background-color: yellow;">this div has background-color inline style without !important</div>
```

Comment: @vickeycolors actually that should be the matter of a different question, you can try with `$.getJSON('test.json', function(data)` and remove `json(test.json);` which is incorrect and becomes useless. If that doesn't work, ask another question, as I am becoming quite busy right now